# ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I am getting this error when records are streamed over to another database

```
Oracle DB version:11.2.0.3.0

Transaction Flow: 
DML on Schema1@DB1 Streamed to Schema2@DB2 then trigger on this table will insert into
Schema3@DB2 then trigger on this table will insert into table in Schema4@DB2

ORA-21780 error happening at the last stage.
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you are trying to keep too many PL/SQL objects (I mean "TYPE AS OBJECT" objects). There is an internal limitation of around 64k of these per session. This is on the client side (not on server side), so this is a programming error, not related to database administration.

Not if that matters, but if you are simply curious why this message speaks about "durations" [see this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci13oca.htm#435278).